# Gerar imagem com texto

Tags: android, bitmap

Gostaria de gerar imagens com textos dinâmicos!

```
public void generate()
{

    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);  
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    String yourText = "Este é meu texto personalizado que vou adicionar em uma imagem de teste qwerty yrrwwq";

    Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(35);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    cs.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);

    cs.drawText(yourText, 10, 50, tPaint);
    try {
        dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ImageAfterAddingText.jpg")));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: Resultado:]

Gostaria de saber como faço para quebrar o texto?

Será necessário calcular quantos caracteres cabem, e adicionando cada linha?

Ou existe alguma forma de quebrar automaticamente?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Olá, por que precisa que o texto seja parte da imagem ? por que não colocar apenas o texto sobre a imagem ?

Comment: pois será exportado! Não se trata de uma tela, e sim um resultado que será gerado para o usuário exportar